# Docusign envelope with multiple documents / recipients but different counter signatures

Tags: docusignapi

In Docusign, is there a way to send a single envelope containing multiple documents, to multiple recipients but have each document countersigned by a different party without exposing the other parties' documents. Here's an example scenario:

### Envelope

```
Recipients:

- Recipient A
- Recipient B

Documents:

- Document 1 (Sent to Recipient A + B but countersigned by Counter Signee 1)
- Document 2 (Sent to Recipient A + B but countersigned by Counter Signee 2)
```

The key for us is to allow Recipient A + B to sign both documents in a **single** signing session and have both documents countersigned by two parties while not allowing them to see the other Counter Signee's documents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document visibly](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-visibility) to restrict who sees what.

However, if I am to sign a document - I have to see it. That's a logical requirement even in the days of paper. Unless you used invisible ink or something that is not possible.

Your scenario is confusing to me because you have only 2 documents and 2 signers and you want them both to sign each, in which case they have to see these documents.

If you only want them to see the pages in the document that contain signing elements (tabs) then you need to separate them into separate documents and hide the other documents using the document visibility feature.

**UPDATE:** maybe you have 4 recipients, not 2, so then yes - you can do this, no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. A more logical example that two documents (say a rental agreement document and an insurance policy) would need to be signed by myself and my partner, but both of those documents would also need a third signature (which I called a counter signature). The person at the rental company would need to counter sign the rental agreement, without seeing the insurance policy. The person at the insurance company would need to counter sign the insurance policy without seeing the rental agreement.

Comment: Also yes, maybe my lack of understanding but 4 recipients, 2 recipient seeing both documents and two other recipients ONLY seeing their document.